# Second time I click "Flag"

Tags: bug, flags

When I flag a question with:

> -> it should be closed for another reason.
>   -> Off topic
>   -> Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

And then go back, and click on the `flag` link again, I see this:

[image]

Don't know if it's a bug or something, but I never flagged the post as a duplicate. Does anyone have the view, and if so, does anyone know why the `duplicate` flag is inactive saying it already has been raised?

Comment: "you have already raised this **type** of flag" Both of those flags go to the same queue (but your message is preserved). Sending two flags to the same queue would serve no purpose

Comment: It says "you have already raised **this type of flag**" and not *this flag*

Comment: @RichardTingle I wasn't going to flag it twice, I just noticed this and couldn't find out why. Then, ***this type of flag***, I think `duplicate` and `another reason` are totally different types, IMO it shouldn't be under one type.

Comment: Just read your link @RichardTingle, thanks! Found the answer.

Comment: @JoranDenHouting Not saying you were "going to", just that that is what it's there to prevent

Comment: @JoranDenHouting Glad to hear it. I get that they feel different, but they are both "Recommend closure" flags (as opposed to recommend deletion)